# xamarin android reward video

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play-services

Hy Eveyone !
I'm trying to make a "Watch Ad" button for win some "lifes" with Xamarin Android.

I think it's because of the ad_unit_id... I just create a RewardVideo, I get the ca-app-pub-XXXX/XXXX and I had UnityAds for the source

I've this code

```
IRewardedVideoAd ad;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
....
ad = MobileAds.GetRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
ad.RewardedVideoAdListener = this;
ad.LoadAd("ca-app-pub-9634192908607048/4854564412", new AdRequest.Builder().Build());

Button adBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonAd);
adBtn.Click += AdBtn_Click;
...
}

private void AdBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ad.Show();
}
```

But that's always respond when I click = "The reward video has not loaded."

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should implement an adlistener. as such:

```
namespace Ads
{
    public static class AdWrapper
    {
        public static InterstitialAd ConstructFullPageAdd(Context con, string UnitID)
        {
            var ad = new InterstitialAd(con);
            ad.AdUnitId = UnitID;
            return ad;
        }
        public static InterstitialAd CustomBuild(this InterstitialAd ad)
        {
            var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            ad.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
            return ad;
        }
    }
}

namespace admobDemo
{
    class adlistener : AdListener
    {
        // Declare the delegate (if using non-generic pattern).
        public delegate void AdLoadedEvent();
        public delegate void AdClosedEvent();
        public delegate void AdOpenedEvent();
        // Declare the event.
        public event AdLoadedEvent AdLoaded;
        public event AdClosedEvent AdClosed;
        public event AdOpenedEvent AdOpened;

        public override void OnAdLoaded()
        {
            if (AdLoaded != null) this.AdLoaded();
            base.OnAdLoaded();
        }
        public override void OnAdClosed()
        {
            if (AdClosed != null) this.AdClosed();
            base.OnAdClosed();
        }
        public override void OnAdOpened()
        {
            if (AdOpened != null) this.AdOpened();
            base.OnAdOpened();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to call `ad.isLoaded` to check if ad is fully loaded then call `ad.Show()` to display ad.

Here is an example:

```
if(ad.IsLoaded){
    ad.Show();
}else{
  //ad is not fully loaded wait a few second then click again to see ads
}
```